# Correctness vs "ownership" on community wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/203686/revisions) has become a CW, presumably because it was edited several times. It cites Martin Fowler, but the quotation is paraphrased, so I edited it, posting the original quote and a link to the document from which came the quote.

The original answerer removed my change. If it were still "his" answer, I would be OK with it, but if it's really going to be CW, doesn't that mean it's owned *by the community*, or am I misunderstanding the semantics of CW?

Comment: From the [history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/203686/revisions) - "Post Made Community Wiki by question having more than 15 answers"

Comment: attribution in CW posts is broken ["by design"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65541/165773 "related MSO discussion")

Comment: If Wikipedia can have edit wars, why can't stack exchange wikis have them too>

Answer (score 2):

The original poster has the same standing to edit as everyone else having sufficient rep to edit.  In fact, suggested edits have pretty much invalidated the notion of community-owned posts (since anyone can suggest an edit).